# After OnRequestFocus() called on View, OnClickListener is not triggering

Tags: android, android-tv

I have a view which gains focus after calling view.requestFocus(), but once the view gets the focus it's onClickListener() is not getting called on click of that view.

Below is my code:
Here btn1 is my view

```
btn1.setFocusable(true);
btn1.requestFocus();
```

Now when my btn1 has the focus I am clicking on that view, but it does nothing, it should show btn2. I have implemented the following callbacks in onViewCreated();

```
btn1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    videoTitleView.setVisibility(GONE);
                    ageRatingView.setVisibility(GONE);
                  
                }
            }
        });

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: newSettings ");
               btn2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        });
```

Am I missing something? How to make the clickEvent execute when view has focus?

Answer (score 0):

Add OnClickListener with in onFocusChange.

```
 public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                videoTitleView.setVisibility(GONE);
                ageRatingView.setVisibility(GONE);
                  btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View view) {
                 Log.d(TAG, "onClick: newSettings ");
                btn2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 });
              
            }
```